# OBSOLETE - SOAPI-EXPLORE: Self-updating single page JavaSript API test harness

Tags: app, obsolete, dev-tool

### SOAPI-EXPLORE

---

<sub>this post was one of the two that were listed regarding SOAPI.</sub>

<sub>For a full overview of the SOAPI eco-system see [What is SOAPI and why should I care?](https://stackapps.com/questions/1352/what-is-soapi-and-why-should-i-care)</sub>

<sub>For a more robust API discovery tool hosted in Silverlight see [Soapi.Explore (silverlight)](https://stackapps.com/questions/1377/soapi-explore-silverlight-the-entire-api-at-your-command)</sub>

---

[image: old screenshot]

[**<del>SOAPI-EXPLORE</del>** (Dead site)](http://soapi.info/Code/JS/Stable/soapi-explore-beta.htm) is a single page JavaScript application that downloads the [<del>latest API spec</del> (Dead site)](http://soapi.info/rest/api?format=json) and dynamically generates a test harness for each route.

All parameters are documented, and as much as is practical, are validated and/or assisted with appropriate input elements.

[**<del>SOAPI-EXPLORE</del>** (Dead site)](http://soapi.info/Code/JS/Stable/soapi-explore-beta.htm) is always up-to-date and in sync with the API.

### DOWNLOAD

Right-click [**<del>SOAPI-EXPLORE</del>** (Dead site)](http://soapi.info/Code/JS/Stable/soapi-explore-beta.htm), select 'save target as...'. All done.

### LICENSE

[**<del>SOAPI-EXPLORE</del>** (Dead site)](http://soapi.info/Code/JS/Stable/soapi-explore-beta.htm) is powered by [SOAPI-WATCH](https://stackapps.com/questions/534/soapi-watch-a-realtime-service-that-notifies-subscribers-via-email-twitter-etc) and is similarly licensed under GPL v2 and MIT licenses.

### CONTACT

Comments, suggestions, complaints, praise and adulation can be registered here or via email to SOAPIWATCH@skysanders.net.

<del>Keep an eye on http://soapi.info/ for all things SOAPI. ;-)</del>

Comment: You should break this post out into two separate ones, one for the [app] and one for the [library].

Comment: Thanks for creating the QUnit tests - it helped me discover that my app was not the problem - but rather the trouble was with the API server.

Comment: All the links to `soapi.info` are dead and the site has no DNS entry.

Comment: 'Google Chrome can't find soapi.info'...