# OBSOLETE - /tags fromdate and todate does nothing

Tags: bug, feature-request, status-completed, obsolete, api-v1

Although the [help/documentation](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/help/method?method=tags) lists `todate` and `fromdate` parameters for tags they do not work. This may be related to tags not having a creation_date. It would be great if we could filter tags by `fromdate` to help us maintain a local tag-cache.

Comment: indeed, those parameters are being ignored. tonklon, for future reference here is a tool for building and debugging queries against the API: http://stackapps.com/questions/1377/soapi-explore-silverlight-the-entire-api-at-your-command

Comment: @Sky Sanders - is support for fromdate/todate on the TODO list ? If so, any idea when it will be implemented?

Comment: Completed / no longer valid as of API version 2 (maybe even 1.1) and [API version 1.x has been offline for years](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/api-v1-shutdown).